# Javascript "addEventListener" Event Fires on Page Load

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

When I run the following script, the event always fires on page load.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I create the element, find it in the DOM then attach a listener, but it always fires the event when the page loads and not when the element is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.write("<div id=\"myDiv\">I am a div</div>");
    el = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    el.addEventListener("click", alert("clicktrack"), false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
el.addEventListener("click", alert("clicktrack"), false);
```

When this line is executed, the `alert` will be called and return `undefined`. To pass the alert code you need to wrap it in a function.

```
el.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("clicktrack"); }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  document.write("<div id=\"myDiv\">I am a div</div>");
  el = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  el.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("clicktrack"); }, false);
</script>
```