# How to use addEventListener for image properly?

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

I like to measure the width of an image, which was loaded by user click. I need the width to adjust the position button next to the image. Is this possible to do in Javascript?

here is my code:

```
document.getElementById('preIMG').addEventListener("load", posButton2IMG); 


function posButton2IMG(){
   var imgWidth = document.getElementById('preIMG').clientWidth;
   var imgWidPos = document.getElementById('picture_preview').clientWidth - imgWidth + 15;
   document.getElementById('gear_butto').style.right = (imgWidPos*0.5) + "px";
}
```

edit:
In fact the user can explore several images and `addEventListener` seems only working for the first time the side is load.

Comment: you can trace the image with by using `new Image` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373995/javascript-addeventlistener-event-fires-on-page-load

Comment: `("load", posButton2IMG())` will not wait for document to load as a function name followed by parenthesis(`()`) means a function call. Try removing the parenthesis

Comment: ok that bring me one step forward... but it only work one time when the user load a new image, the function is not execute again

Comment: Because `document.load` will only fire one time, when the docs are loaded

Comment: This should use styling (CSS), not script.

Comment: @RobG i tried and failed: i have the image in a div that the image is not to big and fixed in the center of the screen. the button goes always on the margin of the div...

Comment: @and I would suggest you to show your HTML as well as tell use what exactly you want to achieve. This way we can suggest something better. But as for now, if I understand correct, try using `display: inline-block` for divs

Comment: @Rajesh `load` means `document.load` and not `image load`? is there a way that each time when the image is loaded new the event will fired?

Comment: @Rajesh thx. i will try and if its not working i will prepare a new question.

Comment: Added a CSS tag so you'll get some attention from those who can provide a non-script solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call function in click event, just pass the function JavaScript will call your function when click event is triggered

```
document.getElementById('preIMG').addEventListener("load", posButton2IMG);
```

Comment: thx but it only work one time, not when the user choose another image from the list.