# cant work out the JS solution

Tags: javascript, challenge-response

I'm trying to work out how to solve this JavaScript code challenge. I'm really struggling and would like some advice please?

I'm trying to improve on my ability to debug and I struggled with this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Click!</button>

<script>
    const counter = {
        cnt: 0,
        inc: function() {
            cnt++;
            console.log(cnt);
        }
    };
    const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc(), false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: cnt is not defined on line 19

Comment: Well what exactly is the problem? What happens? Anything? Errors?

Comment: `cnt` won't be defined in the `inc` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: There are actually two issues. @George duplicate suggestion is right, it will solve your issue. But then you'll encounter another with the way you attach your eventListener because you're not attaching a function reference. Read the accepted answer here : [Javascript "addEventListener" Event Fires on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373995/javascript-addeventlistener-event-fires-on-page-load)

Comment: `counter.cnt++;`

Answer (score 1):

*There's no `cnt` variable defined inside the inc function. It(`cnt`) exists in the object `counter` not in the function `inc`. You could also solve this using the `this` reference. There are several articles in the web about it.*

```
const counter = {
    cnt: 0,
    inc: function() {
        counter.cnt++;
        console.log(counter.cnt);
    }
};
```

Comment: Change this line:
`button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc(), false);`
to:
`button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc, false);`

Comment: "You could also solve this using the this reference". Careful. A solution using `this` in the inc function will not work, because `this` will be a reference to the events target. Unless you add the event listener with `button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc.bind(counter), false)`

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges, yeah.