# How to pass argument to the function without parentheses?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
this.somePromiseFn<T>  // this fn is actually a promise
.then(res => res as T)
.catch(err => this.handleError<T>(err));

handleError<T>(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
  // do something here
  // and return like
  return {} as T;
}
```

The above code works fine. But how I can pass the `err` argument directly to the `handleError` method without using another callback function. As `catch` by default passes the `err` to the callback function, it should also pass the `err` to the `handleCatchError`. I want something like:

```
this.somePromiseFn<T>
.then(res => res as T)
.catch(this.handleCatchError<T>); // this line gives error 'An argument for 'err' was not provided'
```

But the above code produces the error saying:

> Expected 1 argument, but got 0. 
>   An argument for 'err' was not provided.

Though I have visited the following question already:

> 1. [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)
> 2. [Javascript "addEventListener" Event Fires on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373995/javascript-addeventlistener-event-fires-on-page-load)

But the above questions also suggest using another callback function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a [mcve], unless you count the stackblitz link in a comment on one of the answers.  Does `this.someFn().then((r) => console.log(r)).catch(this.cb);` work for you?  If not, please edit this question to constitute a reproducible issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
this.somePromiseFn<T>
.then(res => res as T)
.catch(this.handleCatchError<T>);
```

this should work, tried to reproduce the error but it's working [see a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/skdroid-promise-cb), might be I'm missing something, check and update if necessary.

Comment: Your code is working because you don't have a type variable in your code. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/skdroid-promise-cb-j9zzde?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts), it is not working..!

Answer (score 1):

Based on stackblitz provided by you, see

```
this.someFn().then(r => console.log(r)).catch(err => this.cb<any>(err));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am already using the solution you provided..! But I wanted another (sorter) way..!

Answer (score 0):

Don't give generated type and bind "this":

```
this.somePromiseFn<T>
    .then(res => res as T)
    .catch(this.handleCatchError.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the type variable is required..!

Comment: If you don't call `handleCatchError<T>()` function, you can't give generic type.